# Flutter: How to find code that caused an exception?

Tags: flutter, dart

The exception occurs in the flutter_svg package, and is automatically caught by the library, but it does not provide me the Widget in question and line of code in the app which caused it, only the library code:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SVG ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:
Unable to load asset: "".
The asset does not exist or has empty data.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:331:9)
asset_bundle.dart:331
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:90:27)
asset_bundle.dart:90
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AssetBundlePictureProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:546:25)
picture_provider.dart:546
<asynchronous suspension>

Picture provider: ExactAssetPicture(name: "", bundle: null, colorFilter: null)
Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#f5ca4(), name: "", colorFilter: null,
  theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: Color(0xff000000), fontSize: 16.0, xHeight: 8.0))
═════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I have multiple `SvgPicture.asset()` widgets, and one of them has an empty string at some point in my code. I have too many of these widgets to check individually.

Is there an approach to finding the widget that raised the Exception caught by the library?

Comment: Did you run `flutter pub get` after placing new files into your project?

Comment: @Texv I always do, I found the culprit widget out of luck since I noticed one spot in the UI which didn't load which had a wrong String passed to the widget. However I would really like to know how to debug this if it ever happens again.

Comment: You should be able to pin-point the error with try-catch

Answer (score -1):

## Try searching for the widget,

With VS code try **Ctrl + Shift + F**, then search for `SvgPicture.asset('')` or `SvgPicture.asset("")`

---

### Edit

**Ctrl + Shift + F** Search in VS code should work in general when looking for a specific pattern in code.

[image]

Comment: Please see the end of my question where I have too many of the `SvgPicture.asset()` widgets. Searching through them one by one is impossible to find which is not working that way.

Comment: The end where it states "I have multiple `SvgPicture.asset()` widgets, and one of them has an empty string"? Shouldn't the method in the answer give you the one with the empty string?

Comment: No because when you have a big app, you usually use variables instead of hardcoded strings. I can't search for that.